# Response json Object gets null values

Tags: json, rest, spring-mvc

I'm trying to invoke following code.

```
        // object 
        LoginVM loginVM = new LoginVM();
        loginVM.setUserName("admin");
        loginVM.setUserPassword("s@1234");
        loginVM.setClientIpAddress("::1");
        loginVM.setIsPinActive(false);
        loginVM.setLoginWithPIN(false);


        //connection
        URL url = new URL("http://192.168.202.118/UMService/UserLogin/Login");
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
        conn.setRequestProperty( "Content-Type", "application/json"); 

        conn.setDoOutput(true); //this is to enable writing
        conn.setDoInput(true);  //this is to enable reading

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

        String jsonInString = mapper.writeValueAsString(loginVM);
        System.out.println(jsonInString);



        ObjectOutputStream  out = new ObjectOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
        out.writeObject(jsonInString);
        out.flush();
```

The service is successfully . But LoginVM 's values got null.Could you please point what is the error I have made?

Comment: can you give error message?

Comment: No Error message.Just get null.It successfully hit the server.but object gets null values

Comment: you have to create List<LoginVM > loginVMList = new ArrayList<LoginVM >(); and loginVMList.add(loginVM ); and pass mapper.writeValueAsString(loginVMList);

Comment: Try to use gson

Answer (score 0):

Should work with something like:

JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();

JSONObject jsonObj = (JSONObject) parser.parse(jSonResponse);

You need to check the object in which you are assigning the response.
Also, check among JsonObject or array accordingly.